# Запустить свою activity по кнопке Recent apps

Tags: android, activity

Как сделать, что бы моя активность открывалась при нажатии кнопки Recent apps?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: к счастью, это невозможно (без рут прав)

Comment: @metalurgus, поддерживаю